# Angular CLI support for subdomain reverse proxy

Tags: firebase, angular-cli, subdomain, reverse-proxy, nrwl

suppose id like to have the following reverse proxy url redirection (for page loads):

```
https://abc.example.develop > http://localhost:4200
https://xyz.example.develop > http://localhost:4201
```

is there built-in reverse proxy support for subdomains in angular (cli) or [nx](https://nrwl.io/nx)? recently firebase has added support for multiple subdomains but how is one to serve them in development considering 1) they are different domains 2) firebase apis require https?

both the `proxy.config.js` way (https://angular.io/guide/build#bypass-the-proxy) and the environment files way look like they're made for a single app. do i need to make my own reverse proxy?

Comment: Can you provide more info on the setup? Do you want to visit abc.example.com and xyz.example.com via the browser? Or are you making XHR calls from one subdomain to another?

The built-in support can help you with the latter (you need to modify proxy.config in every app that needs to do this).

For the former case, you need to set that up yourself (using nginx, using containers, etc)

Comment: right. its the former case (url redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do this outside of what Angular provides, since it is custom to your local machine.

The easiest option is to run nginx (or other reverse-proxy) locally (See https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-a-request-to-a-proxied-server)

Modifying your HOSTS file won't forward the port, so if you want to go that route, you'd need to use `https://abc.example.develop:4200`

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a solution](https://github.com/unitedhubs/reverse-proxy-schematic) that executes with the Angular CLI and where the proxy is run on a Node.js server. Nx support is in the [proposal stage](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/875) at the moment.